# Kibana indexing issues

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Not able to project the data in kibana
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Trying to query 1469 shards, which is over the limit of 1000. This limit exists because querying many shards at the same time can make the job of the coordinating node very CPU and/or memory intensive.

Answer (score 0):

The number of shards for the query is exceeding a 1000, which is the default limit. It is unusual to need to go over that limit. You can change it, if you need to:

```
action.search.shard_count.limit
```

But firt it is recommended to look into it and see if you can reduce the number of shards.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_search_shard_limit